# Meaning of $\bar{i}:=i+n\mathbb{Z}$ in Modular Arithmetic

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

I am starting to learn graph theory and ran into the following definition:

> The set $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ of integers modulo $n$ is denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_n$; its elements are written as $\color{red}{\bf\bar{i}:=i+n\mathbb{Z}}$.

Does this imply that

$$
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_n=\left\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\right\}?
$$

Moreover, I have no clue what the author means with the expression in red.

Comment: The notation itself is not directly related to graph theory. Most likely the author has knowledge of modular arithmetic and its accompanying notations as a (possibly implicit) prerequisite.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will update the OP accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ as $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, but the formal mathematical way of defining $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is as a "quotient ring" of the ring $\mathbb Z$ by its "ideal" $n\mathbb Z$.

One way of looking at it is that if we define $a\equiv b\pmod n$ to mean that $a-b$ is divisible by $n$, then $a+n\mathbb Z$ is the set of all $b\in\mathbb Z$ such that $a\equiv b\pmod n$.  For example, when $n=3$, then $1+3\mathbb Z=4+3\mathbb Z=7+3\mathbb Z$, etc. Note that this is exact equality - the sets are exactly the same.

So $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ consists of just the elements $0+3\mathbb Z,1+3\mathbb Z,2+3\mathbb Z$. There really isn't much difference from your intuition, but there is something more general going on here that, when dealing other rings that have more complicated ideals, can become much more interesting.

The main reason for the two notations, $\bar a$ and $a+n\mathbb Z$, is that the first notation is shorter, but hides the $n$. If you are using the same $n$ throughout your problem, then $\bar a$ is okay. But if you are looking at two different rings, $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$, then you might want to be more specific about the "modulus."

Quite often, if it is "obvious," we'll just skip notation altogether and write $1\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Better to learn the "real" definition first, however.

An example is that $\bar 3\cdot \bar 4 =\overline{12}$ no matter what $n$ is. But if $n=5$, then $\overline{12} =\bar 2$, while if $n=7$, $\overline{12}=\bar 5$.

Answer (score 4):

Using your author's notation, $$\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z = \mathbb Z_n = \{\bar{0}, \bar{1}, \bar{2}, \cdots \overline{n - 1}\}$$

where, e.g., $\bar{0} = \{0 + n\mathbb Z\} = \{0,\pm n, \pm 2n \ldots\}$

And in general, for each $i$, $0\leq i \leq n-1,\; \bar i = i + n\mathbb Z = \{i + n k, k\in \mathbb Z\}$

An "element" $\bar i$ is really a subset of the intergers: a special set called the *equivalence class of $i$, modulo $n$. Sometimes the "bar" is dropped, and we use just $i$ to represent the equivalence class of **all integers whose remainder is $i$ when divided by $n$.**

So, for example, in $$\mathbb Z_4 = \{\bar 0, \bar 1, \bar 2, \bar 3\},$$ $$\bar 2 = \{\ldots, -6, -2, 2, 6, \ldots\}$$ where $\bar 2$ is the set of all integers whose remainder is $2$ when divided by $4$.

Comment: The change is still a little wrong. $\bar i = i+n\mathbb Z$, not $\{i+n\mathbb Z\}$. Probably close enough, though.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I understand the confusion.