# What are $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb Z_n$?

Tags: group-theory, notation, modular-arithmetic

Is this correct?

$$\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$$

And what about, for example,

$$\mathbb Z_2=\left\{[0],[1]\right\}=\left\{\{...,-2,0,2,...\},\{...,-3,-1,1,3,...\}\right\}$$

Comment: the first notation is abusive in the sense that actually $0,1,2,...$ are also equivalence classes like in the example you wrote below.

Comment: This is interesting. How would I then write a set which contains $0$, $1$, and $2$ if I can't write $\{0,1,2\}$?

Comment: you can, namely $\{0,1,2\}$ that's way the above first notation is abusive.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/424567/9003)

Comment: @amWhy Coincidentally I saw it (and upvoted it) right after I asked this question. Thanks for the great, comprehensive answer!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: The fact that the notation is abusive does not mean that you cannot use it, provided that you understand what you are doing, which is writing $k$ when you really mean $[k]$. I do myself frequently, since it is convenient if you are doing a lot of arithmetic with this group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first formula, typically, no. By definition, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a factor group. The set underlying this group is $\{i+n\mathbb{Z}\mid i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ $=$ $\{[0],[1],...,[n-1]\}$.

The second notation $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a matter of definition. Authors can define it as $\{0,1\}$, or as $\{[0],[1]\}$, or as something completely different.

Comment: This is really strange, as a book I'm reading says that the set $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is a set with four elements

Comment: I see, now it makes sense. Thank you.